# Splitting Nav Items Using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically I am trying to split the last two items from the other items in my li to sit at flex-end of the `.nav-content` container. I realize my issue is stemming from the fact that I currently have `width: 50%;` set to my `ul class="nav-links"` but that was the only way I could get the spacing between my items to demonstrate what I am trying to do. Ideally, I just want to move the two last items `.login-button first-login` and `.login button second-login` to the end of the container `.nav-content` while keeping the spacing between the items to how they are now.

I tried setting `margin-left: auto` on the `.login-button` class but because the margin is set to 50% it attempts to wrap the buttons and cuts them off. I also tried setting the width to 100% (width of `.nav-content` container) but then the spacing between items gets thrown off.

I know there is probably a simple solution to this that I am not seeing and would greatly appreciate the help!

```css
.nav-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;   
}

.nav-links a.item {
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-links a.item:hover {
    color: black;
}

.nav-links a.item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav-links a.item:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.nav-links li a.login-button {
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px -10px rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.2);
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.nav-links li a.login-button:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
   <header id="header">
        <section class="wrapper">
            <nav class="nav-content">
                <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="login-button first-login">First Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="login-button second-login">Second Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>    
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehting like this?

Wrap the two buttons in another ul to the end of the container...
like:

```
<ul class="nav-links navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Check the code below

```css
.nav-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;   
}

.nav-links a.item {
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-links a.item:hover {
    color: black;
}

.nav-links a.item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav-links a.item:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.nav-links li a.login-button {
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px -10px rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.2);
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float: right;
}

.nav-links li a.login-button:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
        <section class="wrapper">
            <nav class="nav-content">
                <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Item 4</a></li>
                   
                </ul>
        <ul class="nav-links navbar-nav ml-auto">
 <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="login-button first-login">First Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="login-button second-login">Second Login</a></li>
        </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>    
    </header>
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I knew it would be something simple. Thank you.